# import behaves differently when executing the script in different ways?

Tags: python, import

assuming we have this file tree :

```
test
├── config.py
├── main.py
└── network
    └── arduino.py
```

as you can see below `main.py` imports `arduino.py` and `arduino.py` imports a variable from `config.py` which is in the parent folder of `arduino.py`.
When I run `main.py` everything works perfectly but when I run `arduino.py` I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

I know that we can't import from the parent folder simply as I did, but how this import is done when I execute main.py?

any clarification, please

***arduino.py***

```
from config import some_var  
def fun():
        print(some_var)
fun()
```

***main.py***

```
from network.arduino import *
fun()
```

***config.py***

```
some_var = 10
```

I don't want to import from the parent folder, I'm looking for explanations why this import works fine when the script being executed is located in this parent folder, but it's actually making an import from the actual folder script which is `arduino.py` in my case

Comment: I see, took me a while to understand what exactly you're trying. Executing a file adds its parent folder to the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), which makes imports from that directory possible. This happens implicitly, so there is no way to know about it unless you run into it at some point ... as you did today =)

Comment: thank you, it's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to import a module in a python file, the interpreter looks for a module of that name in a number of directories which are defined by the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. You can access it during runtime via `sys.path`. Printing it in `arduino.py` and executing it shows us why the import only works when running `main.py`:

***arduino.py***

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

from config import some_var  
def fun():
        print(some_var)
fun()
```

When running `python3 main.py`:

```
['/home/user/test', ..., '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'] 
10 
10
```

When running `python3 network/arduino.py`:

```
['/home/user/test/network', ..., '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "network/arduino.py", line 4, in <module>
    from config import some_var  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Since the file `config.py` lies in `/home/user/test` it is found in the first case, but not in the second.

If you want to solve issues surrounding import locations, see the [python packing tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/overview/), which will make absolute imports within your package work.